# Plant Identification: Tall shrub-like plant with fuchsia flowers

Tags: identification, flowers

I'd love help identifying this plant that I spotted in Amman, Jordan. It is about 3 feet tall, and nearly as wide. It seemed to be quite hardy, as it was growing in a break in the sidewalk. It has fuchsia colored flowers, about 1/2" across, with long stamens. The leaves are about 2 - 2 1/2" long. The two photos below are the only ones I have, but hopefully show enough of the flowers and leaves for an identification.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Michelle...I am getting a nose-bleed with this one.  From Malvaceae to Dianthus!  Is this a sub shrub or a perennial?  Dianthus is the closest I've gotten.  I am dying to hear this plant's ID!!

Comment: I really wasn't sure which it was, stormy. I think bamboo got the identification right, and the description on one of the links provided calls it a "bushy perennial." That seems about right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it might be Mirabilis, possibly Mirabilis jalapa, common name four o'clock plant because it tends to open its flowers in the afternoon. Some are annuals, others are tuberous rooted, but in cooler regions like the UK, they're usually grown as annuals

https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/details?plantid=1282

and Wiki entry here

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirabilis_jalapa

There are other Mirabilis varieties - M.longiflora, M.multiflora and M. laevis

Comment: Wow...Bamboo, what do you use for a key?  I know I've asked this before...did you get one of those applications that you have to pay for?  Grins!  Mirabilis wasn't even mentioned anywhere ...good job sweetie!

Comment: @stormy with this plant,. I recognised it immediately, it happens to be one I know, but with others, I just use Google images, having put in a description of key features, so nothing special at all. I also have a very good memory, tho at my age, who knows how long that'll last!

Comment: Grins...you just keep on being our FOUNDATION, your brain will last forever!  How about writing a few books, sweetheart?  Why waste all your knowledge and experience.  For real!!  Look at what you do!  Almost 50k.  My goodness.  Go start a few books.  Have you read Jorge Cervantes The Cannabis Encyclopedia???  One plant, a whole encyclopedia and vastly good information, methodology without having to think about thousands of plants.  I was amazed and think this is a super plant book.  Think about what you could do?!  Hey, has Joe Udwin contacted you?

Comment: No! Who's Joe Udwin? To be honest, I'm having trouble functioning at all, never mind considering what you've said, I'm so depressed at what's going on here in the uk,i feel like someone's died with our referendum result.... I'd emigrate it I could!